# Error lambda AWS .net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, aws, lambda

estoy subiendo un lambda AWS con .net Core 2.1 en visual Studio 2019, pero al momento de consumir se me presenta el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el controlador que tengo es el siguiente:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public IActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            ObjectResult result;
            Documents documents = Consulta.Consul(id);
            if (documents.CaseNumber == null)
            {
                result = new ObjectResult("No existe informacion con el ID de transacción: " + id)
                {
                    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
                };
                _logger.LogWarning(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "--No existe informacion con el ID de transacción: " + id);
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                result = new ObjectResult(documents)
                {
                    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK
                };
                _logger.LogInformation(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "--Consulta correcta: " + id);
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ObjectResult result = new ObjectResult(ex.ToString())
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
            };
            _logger.LogError(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "--" + ex.ToString());
            return result;
        }


    }
```

al ejecutar de modo local el código funciona bien, pero al publicar en AWS se presenta el error, alguien puede ayudarme a detectar que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya logré solucionar, solo toca configurar un enlace del api AWS como proxy asi como está en la figura.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]